# how to update a symbolic link target (ln -f -s not working)

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm using

> ln -f -s
>   /var/www/html/releases/build1390
>   app-current

to update symbolic link "app-current" with a new destination.
However, this doesn't work, the link "app-current" keeps it original destination, however, I don't get any errors...

I'd rather not remove the link and recreate it, just update the target of an existing link. Is that possible?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That works for me, what is the output of `strace ln -f -s /var/www/html/releases/build1390 app-current` ?

Oh, since it is a directory you need to add `-n` for no dereference and this should solve the issue. `-f` is really more of a convenience since adding the -f just causes it to unlink anyways. Although I guess it would probably happen a few hundred ms faster on a normally loaded system.

For example, if arf already points to /home:

strace With `-n`:

```
strace ln -n -f -s / arf
...
symlink("/", "arf")           = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
unlink("arf")                           = 0
symlink("/", "arf")           = 0
```

strace Without `-n`:

```
strace ln -f -s / arf
...
write(2, "ln: "..., 4ln: )                  = 4
write(2, "`arf/': cannot overwrite director"..., 34`arf/': cannot overwrite directory) = 34
write(2, "\n"..., 1)                    = 1
```

So without the `-n` arf gets dereferenced so ln treats it as arf as if it were actually `/`.  In your particular example, if there is no error,  I think you have probably created a new symbolic link inside of `/var/www/html/releases/build1390 app-current` and will want to clean that up.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `-n` or `--no-dereference` to prevent the target from being dereferenced if it is a symlink. You can also use `-T` or `--no-target-directory` to ensure that the target file will *always* be treated as a regular file.

These produce slightly different behavior, as the following example shows. Suppose `src` is some file, `dirlink` is a symlink to a directory, and `dir` is an actual directory.

Using `-n`:

- `ln -sfn src dirlink` overwrites `dirlink` and links it to `src`
- `ln -sfn src dir` creates link `dir/src -> src`

Using `-T`:

- `ln -sfT src dirlink` overwrites `dirlink` and links it to `src`
- `ln -sfT src dir` produces an error message: `ln: ‘dir’: cannot overwrite directory`

Comment: has the most correct and succinct answer for Linux users.

Comment: Is there any way to force overwriting the target directory so you won't get the error message `cannot overwrite directory`?

Comment: @rednaw You can do this by chaining a couple of commands, but `ln` itself does not remove directories – this would probably be a bad idea, because it would require recursively removing a possibly huge number of files.